# Using convention over configuration in Symfony2 controllers/views

Tags: symfony

I have the following Symfony controller:

```php
/** 
 * Says thanks to the user for signing up.
 *
 * @Route("/thanks", name="user")
 * @Template()
 */
public function thanksAction()
{   
  return $this->render('VNNPressboxBundle:User:thanks.html.twig');
}
```

If I don't include the `return` statement, I get an error saying the controller must return a response. It's interesting that I have to manually specify which template my action needs to use, considering Symfony could easily figure that out based on my controller and action. Plus that's how Symfony 1.x worked.

I have to imagine that I'm missing something. It doesn't seem like they would apply the convention over configuration concept in Symfony 1.x and then abandon it in Symfony >= 2.0.

Is it possible to tell Symfony to figure out which template to use based on my controller and action, and if so, how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to return something. You're using @Template annotation so you don't have to render the response but you still have to return an array of parameters for the template (in your case empty):

```php
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;

/** 
 * Says thanks to the user for signing up.
 *
 * @Route("/thanks", name="user")
 * @Template()
 */
public function thanksAction()
{   
  return array();
}
```

Read more on @Template annotation in the docs: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/view.html

P.S. Don't compare symfony 1.x to Symfony 2.x. These are two different frameworks. Symfony 2 favors being explicit over magic.

Answer (score 1):

Return an array. In your case it'll be an empty array, but normally you would fill it with variables you want to pass to a template.